# Iframe blocked by Firefox even if the origin is on the same domain (GLPI)

Tags: html, web, firefox, iframe

I've got a landing page on a domain : **[www.extranet.domain.com](http://www.extranet.domain.com)**
On this page I want to

`<iframe allow-same-origin="true" src="https://anotherdomain.domain.com/page" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%"/></iframe>`

Instead of getting the Iframe, I got a security issue from Firefox saying that I need to open the website in a new window (cf image https://i.stack.imgur.com/0veFo.png)

Thanks for reading !
<smile!>

UPDATE :

The login page of the website (GLPI) on the "anotherdomain.com" works. But When I log-in I got the error !

Comment: I edited the GLPI configuration in /inc/html.class.php and commented the line

```header('x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN')``` and it works ! (but seems not very safe..)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to set the domain for both the landing page and the frame, in order to get your same-origin policy to work.

```
document.domain = "domain.com"
```

...in both.

See the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out!